# Trouble reading/writing file from relative path

Tags: java, file, path

I've been trying to read and write to a file under my resources directory in my project. However, regardless of what I seem to do it doesn't allow me to do so.

This is my project hierarchy for reference:

[image]

Out of all these:

```
Paths.get("memes.txt")
Paths.get("resources/memes.txt")
Paths.get("/resources/memes.txt")
...
```

None have worked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to really read text file from classpath in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a Maven project ?
Try this :

```
//Get file from resources folder
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
```

Ref : https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/

Answer (score 1):

Your application *can* be packed as .jar file - a zip format.
There, or in the built classes directory should be `memes.txt`. A so-called *resource*, and in case of a jar not really a file system file. But is located on the class path.

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/memes.txt");
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/memes.txt");
```

The path is relative to the package directory of the class, or absolute as above.

Answer (score 0):

Try it using "../resources/memes.txt" with ".." you go up one directory from your current file (i assume that you are using the code in SwearTest.java)

Comment: It still throws me `Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: ..\resources\memes.txt`, though. And yes, I am using the code in SwearTest.java